# Obtener el valor de un select

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de que todos los "input text" obtengan el valor de cada select, pero solo me funciona en uno(en el primero).

```js
let combos = document.querySelector(".combos")
        let text_field = document.querySelector(".text_field")

        combos.addEventListener("change",function(){
            text_field.value = combos.value
        })
```

```html
<body>
        <select class="combos">
            <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
            <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
            <option value="Media">Media</option>
            <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="text_field" name="text_field" value="Vacio">

        <br>
        <br>

        <select class="combos">
                <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
                <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                <option value="Media">Media</option>
                <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="text_field" name="text_field" value="Vacio">

        <br>
        <br>

        <select class="combos">
                <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
                <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                <option value="Media">Media</option>
                <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="text_field" name="text_field" value="Vacio">

        <br>
        <br>

        <select class="combos">
                <option value="Vacio" selected>--Seleccione--</option>
                <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                <option value="Media">Media</option>
                <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="text_field" name="text_field" value="Vacio">
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque no es la mejor solución, cambiar tu JS por este hara que funcione:

```
const combos = document.querySelectorAll(".combos")
const text_field = document.querySelectorAll(".text_field")

for (let i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {

  combos[i].addEventListener("change", (e) => {

    text_field[i].value = e.target.value

  })

}
```

No es la mejor solución, pero hará que funcione respetando la estructura que utilizas.

Comment: Para mi si fue la mejor solución :)

Comment: Como no se me ocurrió antes usar el document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Nos pasa a muchos, sobre todo si estás acostumbrado a usar jQuery